# Space exploration alien hide outside visible light

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember much from the book:

A ship is doing exploration when it finds a planet where it looks like the whole planet is cultivated, but no life forms are detected. There are only harvesters and seeding machines on the planet. They wait to see what will happen to the harvest. But then, an alien spaceship lands and an alien comes on board their ship. They can't see the alien or his ship. The alien is surprised to see so many people on the ship, as they live alone. After it kills some crew members, they kill the alien with help of the ship computer. I read this about 30 years ago. Any idea of the name and writer?

Added:
Book
The alien can move outside the visible light
When alien was inside the ship his way was blocked by crew member think he panicked and kill them for that reason

Comment: Found the book, because the library had a mix language I forgot the book was in dutch. The title is "de binaire joker" . https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6425388-de-binaire-joker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long search I found the book, because the library had a mix language I forgot the book was in dutch. The title is *[De Binaire Joker](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1171227)" ([Goodreads link](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6425388-de-binaire-joker)).

Translated summary from [this review of the French translation](http://www.noosfere.org/icarus/livres/niourf.asp?numlivre=1679):

> Leaving for a sidereal cruise of several years, the huge spaceship "Star Squash" docks on an apparently deserted small planet. But, in reality, this strange world is a cosmic barn, the gigantic pantry of an extraterrestrial race. A radio signal will put the crew of the "Squash" for the first time in contact with another form of life, which will prove to be quickly hostile because of fear of the unknown. The fear of the other settles in both camps and leads to psychological warfare and then to a violent open conflict.
>
> When an Extraterrestra manages to enter the "Squash", it is panic among the members of the crew. The Terrans will not have the ability to oppose the wave of terror and horror triggered by this invisible enemy, only the intelligence and the know-how of their computer, Nestor the Binary Buffoon, always on the lookout for a quarrel with Commander Pendelgrass. But this time the precious machine, true repository of human knowledge, will have to have a duel to death with a being come from nothingness...